# How to set different datatype items in same view in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have an app in which I have a custom grid view with image and text view and adapter that populates data in grid view. I have three items with a different type which I populate in views.PLease find the view details of type and views

Views:
a) ImageView
b) TextView

Data:
a) TextDrawable img
b) String name
c) String imageUrl

Now, What I want to do to set img and imageurl in Imageview. If i got img="String" then set ImageDrawable in imageView and if i get imageUrl="http..." then set that image in Imageview. Ho do i do that pls help.

code of data model

```
 private String name;
private TextDrawable img;
private String imageurl;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public TextDrawable getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(TextDrawable img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public String getImageurl() {
    return imageurl;
}

public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
    this.imageurl = imageurl;
}
```

code of Adapter class

```
private ArrayList<UserListingModel> dataModel;
Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public NameListingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserListingModel> models) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataModel = models;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dataModel.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView tv;
    CircleImageView img;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_name_list_items, null);
    holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img = (CircleImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


    holder.tv.setText(dataModel.get(position).getName());
    holder.img.setImageDrawable(dataModel.get(position).getImage());
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, DashBoardMain.class);
            i.putExtra("Name", dataModel.get(position).getName());
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

Overall what i want to do is to set to different types in GridView ImageVie/w

Comment: You should probably have to learn to use `getItemViewType()` and `getItemViewTypeCount()`. So many tutorials are there for it. just google it.

Comment: any link.................